# SQlite3 syntax error UPDATE statement on flask - python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, sql-update

i've developed a APIful webapp using sqlite3 and flask framework with python, i have an external client that sends POST request, and it works correctly.

On my Windows environment the update query works correctly, when i try to execute all on my CentOS environment my query it return a syntax error, the following code is:

````
    @app.route('/apis/rcvInfo', methods=['POST'])
    def form_to_json():
        if request.method == "POST":
            table=request.form['table']
            status=str(request.form['status'])

            ####query operations
            nEntries = (sendQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) AS RowCnt  FROM "+table))[0]
            if (nEntries > 0 ):
                sendQuery("UPDATE "+table+" SET status = "+status+", lastcheck=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY lastcheck DESC LIMIT 1")
            else:
                sendQuery("INSERT INTO "+table+" (status) VALUES ("+status+")")
                
            db.get_db().commit()

            return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'} ``` 

def sendQuery(query):
    cursor = db.get_db().cursor()
    print (query)
    cursor.execute(query)
    records = cursor.fetchone()

    return records
````

On my Windows environment the UPDATE statement work correctly, updating the first row.

But on my CentOS env i have the following error message:

`sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ORDER": syntax error`

The params (table, status) are correct.

Comment: Does UPDATE really have an ORDER BY clause in SQLite?

Comment: Can't see how this error is OS-specific. Generally in SQL, `ORDER BY` is not used in `UPDATE` actions.

Comment: From: https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html#optional_limit_and_order_by_clauses: *If SQLite is built with the SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT compile-time option then the syntax of the UPDATE statement is extended with optional ORDER BY and LIMIT* So no, ORDER BY is not supported in UPDATE in common releases of SQLite.

Comment: @jarlh why in my windows environment it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [2.3. Optional LIMIT and ORDER BY Clauses](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html#optional_limit_and_order_by_clauses):

> If SQLite is built with the [SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT](https://sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit)
> compile-time option then the syntax of the UPDATE statement is
> extended with optional ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses...

So in a common release of SQLite you can't use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` with an `UPDATE` statement.

In your case as a workaround, if the column `lastcheck` contains unique values you can do this:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET status = ?,
    lastcheck = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE lastcheck = (SELECT MAX(lastcheck) FROM tablename)
```

or:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET status = ?,
    lastcheck = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE lastcheck = (SELECT lastcheck FROM tablename ORDER BY lastcheck DESC LIMIT 1)
```

If the column `lastcheck` does not contain unique values you could use the column `rowid` in the `ORDER BY` clause of the subquery to break any ties:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET status = ?,
    lastcheck = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE lastcheck = (SELECT lastcheck FROM tablename ORDER BY lastcheck DESC, rowid DESC LIMIT 1)
```